# Word for anger out of concern [for another]?

Tags: single-word-requests, connotation

*Fearful anger* is the closest I've found—compound words/phrases are acceptable, but I'm really looking for a single word.

A context example: if a friend or loved one does something reckless and/or dangerous, and you scold them after. You're angry with them, but the anger is out of concern for their well-being.

Alarm: covers the anxiety, but I'm not sure if it encapsulates the 'anger' right.

Ideas?

Comment: _Upset_ might work in the context. It can include both being worried and angry. [_Macmillan_](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/upset_1#upset_1__1) definition: "very sad, worried, or angry about something"

Comment: Do you have an example sentence you would use it in?